# Issue with SQL query

Tags: sql, count, subquery

This is supposed to be a very simple problem, but somehow I am completely stuck... This is a simplified example to show the problem:

```
Table:
int     ID (primary key)
varchar Child
varchar Toy
```

Running

```
SELECT Child, Toy FROM TestTable
```

gives me:

```
Child    Toy
------------------------
A        T_A
B        T_B
A        T_C
C        T_D  
A        T_E
B        T_F
```

I need a query that returns me the Child/Toy entries only for children that have more then 2 toys - only one in this example. So the output should look like this:

```
Child    Toy
------------------------
A        T_A
A        T_C
A        T_E
```

Comment: For clarity, it would be useful if you could specify which flavour of SQL you are programming for

Answer (score 8):

This finds children with more than two toys:

```
select Child
from TestTable
group by Child
having count(*) > 2
```

Then you can do this to get all columns back that you want:

```
select Child, Toy
from TestTable 
where Child in (
    select Child
    from TestTable
    group by Child
    having count(*) > 2
)
```

Comment: Actually it finds children with more than one ROW. OP should be advised this will count duplicate toys as well.

Comment: +1 : And, I'd JOIN rather than using IN.  But it's the same concept :)

Comment: Thank you for your really fast response, but this does not give me the desired output. I need 'Child' and 'Toy' in the output, so SELECT Child, Toy ....

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Child, Toy
FROM TestTable
WHERE Child IN
(
    SELECT Child
    FROM TestTable
    GROUP BY Child
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Child, Toy
FROM TestTable
WHERE child IN(
   SELECT Child FROM TestTable group by Child having count(*)>2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work

```
SELECT
    Child,
    Toy
FROM TestTable t
WHERE
    t.Child IN 
    (
        SELECT Child
        FROM TestTable  
        GROUP BY Child
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 2         
    )
```